# Nodejs if file exists from different url

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to check if image exists using absolute path? I have 2 apps using one domain, but with different ports. I want to check if the file exists on other app. For example from www.domain.com:80 I want to check if this file exists: www.domain.com:8080/images/image1.jpg. I have tried to do it with `fs.exists`, `fs.existsSync`, `fs.Stats`, but it on the first 2 functions it always returns false and on the `fs.Stats` it returns error "ENOENT, no such file or directory", but I can view the file entering url on browser. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fs functions look for files on your *local* filesystem.  If you want to see if a remote file exists, you'll have to make an HTTP request using the [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or the like.